# iCloud sync plist file

Tags: ios, synchronization, icloud, icloud-api

I'm not good in programming, this is my first app. 
I have made app using this tutorials:
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/building-a-shopping-list-application-from-scratch-part-1/?search_index=4
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/building-a-shopping-list-application-from-scratch-part-2/?search_index=2

All data is stored in plist file. Everything works fine. But now i want to make icloud sync, i tried to find solutions but most of tutorials is about how to sync Core Data or just NSUserDefaults.

Can you please show maybe some code at github that i can use or some tutorials "How to sync plist file".

Answer (score 0):

This document contains what you need to know to get started with iCloud. It has NSUserDefaults, Core Data, and Documents. iCloud can be a difficult technology to work with. You'll learn more by reading the documentation directly. Tutorials can be good, but they won't be able to cover everything. If you want to truly learn it and understand how it works, read Apple's official docs.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/Introduction.html